# When water turns to steam at 100 degrees Celsius why does both the internal and potential energy increase?

Tags: energy, temperature, potential-energy

I thought during this transition only the potential energy increases as energy is used to weaken the van Der Waal forces  between the molecules.  And that the internal energy is only dependent on the change in kinetic energy . So why does internal energy increase? Thankyou for the help.

Comment: This might be a question of terminology.  I'm not certain that there is 100% consensus about this, but in my usage internal energy is potential energy plus thermal energy.  The phrase "internal energy is only dependent on the change of kinetic [do you mean thermal?] energy" would apply only to an ideal gas where there is no potential energy.

Comment: Oh so this equation won't apply for water or anything else rather than an ideal gas?

Comment: Which equation do you mean?

Comment: Internal energy = kinetic energy + potential energy . Is this only for ideal gas?

Comment: I misspoke above, since I had an equation stuck in my head that you were not addressing.  So ignore my first comment.  Internal energy comprises all forms of energy other than the macroscopic KE of the sample as it moves as a whole.  So internal energy is kinetic plus potential.   An ideal gas has no potential energy, and no intramolecular structure, so for an ideal gas  internal energy = internal translational kinetic energy.  For your steam conversion, the temperature remains constant so the average translational kinetic energy per molecule remains constant.

Comment: So if kinetic energy remains constant then the internal energy is only increasing due to the rise in potential energy? But how does this potential energy increase ? Is it because the molecules are moving far apart?

Comment: Yes to both quesitons, but please note that *kinetic energy* usually refers to the overall macroscopic KE of the object.  In this context it would be better to clarify what you mean:  *average translational kinetic energy per molecule* or perhaps shorter *internal translational kinetic energy*.  It's a mouthful, I agree, but your usage sounds a little strange to my ear.

Comment: Oh sorry I will use the correct term from now on . Thanks a lot! I finally understand this!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms the internal energy can be thought of as the sum of the kinetic energy and the potential energy of the molecules.

The kinetic energy of the molecules depends on the temperature - a higher temperature means that the molecules have more kinetic energy.
The potential energy of the molecules depends on the bonds (interactions) between them - breaking bonds requires work to be done and that means that there is a increase in the potential energy.

So converting water at $100\;^\circ$C into steam at $100\;^\circ$C makes no change to the kinetic energy of the molecules but increases the potential energy of the molecules (bonds are broken) and so the internal energy of steam is greater than that of water.

Comment: I think that what you wrote works for *atoms* but not for *molecules* where the kinetic energy associated with internal degrees of freedom does not contribute to temperature.   This question is a good example of needing to be more strict about language than usual.  "The *translational* kinetic energy of the molecules depends on the temperature ..." etc.